# What is the priority level of multi prefix match in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

```
location ^~ /upload/images/ {
     return 200;
}
location ^~ /admin/ {
     return 300;
}
```

When I visit `http://ip/admin/upload/images/pic.jpg` , it return 300.

How could I do to make `http://ip/admin/upload/images/pic.jpg` and `http://ip/upload/images/pic.jpg` and `http://ip/anyother/upload/images/pic.jpg` return 200

Comment: But regex has lower priority than ^~   .  And  http://ip/task/upload/images/pic.jpg  match the first location

Comment: You cannot achieve this with two prefix locations. You will need to add a third  prefix location, like: `location ^~ /admin/upload/images/` to handle URIs beginning with `/admin`.

Comment: Thx. I have find a way to resolve this. I seems that I can't handle all uris which I want to block in one location.